# Change default UpdateSourceTrigger for Textbox.Text?

Tags: c#, wpf

### Background

I'd like to change WPF's `Textbox.Text`'s default `UpdateSourceTrigger` from `LostFocus` to `PropertyChanged` I've seen a few older questions seeking to do the same thing however, I haven't found a reasonable response.

### What I've Tried

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxBase}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Binding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Style>
```

I've tried changing it in a style with no luck.

### The Question

How do I change the default `TextBox.Text`'s `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for every `TextBox`?

### Notes

- I'd prefer not creating a new class that inherits from `TextBox` as I already have quite a few.

Comment: A markup extension is the way to go.  It may have upsides and downsides you're not happy with, but it's deffo the way to approach it.